# Время подключения Channel-ов в Netty

Tags: java, netty

Можно ли каким-то образом в Netty узнать, когда был создан тот или иной Channel? Или настроить Bootstrap, ChannelConfig или что-либо ещё так, чтобы Channel-ы автоматически закрывались через N-ое время после открытия (будут ли идти данные - не важно)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно хранить список подключений.

К примеру, для http сервера при создании обработчика он наследуется от `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`.

Там вы можете переопределить методы:

```
@Override
public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelRegistered(ctx);
    // добавить канал в список
}

@Override
public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super. channelUnregistered(ctx);
    // удалить канал из списка
}
```

В `channelRegistered` вы можете добавить канал в какой-нибудь свой список и запомнить время подключения. В `channelUnregistered` удалять. 
Периодически прогоняйте этот список и отключайте канал по прошествии какого-то времени, если необходимо.